# Wrong output while merging sorted arrays of equal length

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to merge 2 sorted arrays of equal length. However, I'm not getting the desired output.
Here is my code:

```
    public static int[] mergeSorted(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
        int n = arr2.length;

        int[] ans = new int[2*n];

        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while(i < n && j < n){
            if(arr1[i] <= arr2[j]){
                ans[k] = arr1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else{
                ans[k] = arr2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i < n){
            ans[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

        while(j < n){
            ans[k] = arr2[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }


        return ans;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 100, 34, 29};
        int[] arr2 = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 9, 13, 300};

        int[] ans = mergeSorted(arr1, arr2);

        for(int el : ans)
            System.out.print(el + " ");
    }
```

Output:

1 2 3 4 5 6 9 13 100 34 29 300

Clearly, this is not correct. However, this code works for smaller inputs. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Test cases were wrong as they were not sorted. Code was fine.

Comment: easiest approach: add all the elements, then run a sorting algorithm.

Comment: I know there are other ways to solve this but I want to know what I'm particularly doing wrong here.

Comment: Your method would work if your two input arrays were sorted.

Comment: Your title says you want to merge two sorted arrays, and yet your first array is unsorted.

Comment: @NomadMaker I have mentioned it in the edits section of my question.

Answer (score 1):

For the `merge` operation to work, the two arrays you are merging should be in sorted order. The first array is not in sorted order:

```
    int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 100, 34, 29};
```

Change it to:

```
    int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 29, 34, 100};
```

Comment: And that is why I refrain from using random test cases which pop into my head. Thanks a ton!